# Accidentally moved encfs encrypted directory, can't decrypt

Tags: encfs

I accidentally moved an encfs-encrypted directory. I moved it back once I realized my mistake, but now whenever I try to decrypt it normally, with the same command that worked before:

```
encfs ~/.stuff-encrypted ~/.stuff
```

It now gives me the prompts as if I were setting it up.

I remember all the settings I chose (AES-256, etc.) and the password. So how do I decrypt the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that I just needed to specify a different target directory than the previous target directory I was using.

The `~/.stuff` directory already existed and sat in my home directory just for me to point encfs to it. Typing

```
encfs ~/.stuff-encrypted ~/.new-stuff-directory
```

worked just fine, with the usual password prompt *rather* than trying to setup a new encrypted volume. I struggled to remember the password four months later, but then it opened just fine.